# Element shrink and growth with css

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox, grid

I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve this kind of thing (attached image). Lets say I have 7 buttons and they span across declared width, but when I want to add other element or more those buttons should shrink. Is it possible to achieve this with css only like flex or grid. All I can do is to span one button across width, but when I add another it immediately display as inline and add next button to it, not under.
[image: First Window]
[image: Second Window]

Comment: can you use scss or sass?

Comment: Yes I can use it, but still I don't know how to do it

Comment: you can achieve it using CSS grids. refer (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: I know I can use grid and flexbox. Question is how?

Comment: do you know the amount of buttons before the break?

Comment: @Dejan.S see my answer and trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flebox`

**The trick about number of divs is :**

```
        .right-side button:nth-last-child(8):first-child,
        .right-side button:nth-last-child(8):first-child ~ *{
           //set style if only when you have more then 7 buttons inside .right-side dive.... 
              else(less then 8) nothing will happend
        }
```

**Also position the div that 8+:**

```
.right-side button:nth-child(n+8){
float: right;
position: relative;
top: calc(-100vh + (100vh / 7 - 1px));
}
```

**Here is full code:**

```css
    .wrap{
        display:flex;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .left-side,.right-side{
        width:50%;
        height:100vh;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    .left-side{
      background:pink;
    }
    .right-side{
   position: relative;
    }
    .right-side button{
     width:100%;
     height:calc(100vh / 7 - 1px);
     background:pink;
     
    }

    .right-side button:nth-last-child(n+8):first-child,
    .right-side button:nth-last-child(n+8):first-child ~ *{
     width:50%;
    }
    .right-side button:nth-child(n+8){
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: calc(-100vh + (100vh / 7 - 1px));
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="left-side"></div>
        <div class="right-side">
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Same style with 7 buttons</h1>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="left-side"></div>
        <div class="right-side">
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it takes a lot of times but i did it :) happy coding

Comment: happy to help:)